# webserver not receiving while function in a module is busy

Tags: lua, webserver, esp8266

I am rather new to LUA and not too much experienced.

I am using a webserver on a nodemcu esp8266, that is controlling a steppermotor which is turning a gimbal. For that I found a stepper module which is working fine. There is a command for turning the motor like this: turn(mno,direction,pan_speed,no_steps)
This works fine.
I would like now to have the motor turning until another command from the webserver stops it.
Here I need an advice. I can start the motor from within the webserver using a loop that executes the command in the module. This also works, but I cannot stop the motor because the webserver is not receiving the stop command as long as the loop is turning the motor.I have tried with timer, but I still have not perfectly understood the eventhandling in LUA.

Any advice is very welcome

Derek

This is the main program. As I am tryings, different things only the part which is turning the gimbal left is relevant. While the program is turning left it cannot accept a second command to turn left again that should stop the gimbal.

Important is the part in the webserver where the gimbal shold turn left and then the function "turn" in the stepper module.

```
    motors  = require ('stepper')

    pan_speed = 1
    tilt_speed = pan_speed

    pan_steps=50
    tilt_steps=pan_steps

    steps = 50
    mno=1

    gol=1
    gor=0

    stop=1

    -- a simple http server
    if srv ~= nil then
      --srv:close()
    end

    srv=net.createServer(net.TCP,180) 
    srv:listen(80,function(conn) 
        conn:on("receive",function(conn,request) 
            -- print(node.heap())
            buf = ""
            local buf = "";
                buf = buf.."HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n"
            local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
            if(method == nil)then
                _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
            end
            local _GET = {}
            if (vars ~= nil)then
                for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
                    _GET[k] = v
                end
            end


            if(_GET.direction or _GET.speed) or _GET.distance then

                if(_GET.direction) == "left"  then
                    print("pressed left")
                    dir = -1
                    if stop==0 then stop=1 elseif stop == 1 then stop=0 end
                    print("stop = ",stop)
                    buf = "OK" 
                    mno=1  
                    while stop == 0 do
                        turn(mno,dir,pan_speed,1)   
                    end
                 end

                if(_GET.direction) == "right" then
                    if stop==0 then stop=1 elseif stop == 1 then stop=0 end
                    buf = "OK"
                    mno=1 
                    while stop == 0  do 
                    print("gimbal dreht rechts")
                    --turn(mno,1,1,1)
                    end
                end

                if(_GET.direction) == "up" then
                    buf = "OK"
                    mno=2
                    --turn(mno,1,tilt_speed,tilt_steps)
                end

                if(_GET.direction) == "down" then
                    buf = "OK"
                    mno=2
                    --turn(mno,-1,tilt_speed,tilt_steps)
                    --collectgarbage()
                end

                if(_GET.speed) then
                    buf = "OK"
                    pan_speed = _GET.speed
                    tilt_speed = pan_speed
                    collectgarbage()
                end

                if(_GET.distance) then
                    buf = "OK"
                    pan_steps = tonumber(_GET.distance)
                    tilt_steps = pan_steps
                    collectgarbage()
                end
                --write_config() 
                collectgarbage()
            end

            conn:send(buf)
            -- srv:close()
            collectgarbage()




            print("stop 3 = ",stop)
        end) 
        print("stop 2 = ",stop)

end)
```

And here is the stepper module:

```
stepper = {}
do

    local mot = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

    -- direction = 1
    steps = 50
    speed = 4
    del = 1000 * speed
    print("Modul del = ",del)
    mno = 1
    pan_pos = 0

    gpio.mode(12, gpio.INPUT)
    gpio.write(12, gpio.HIGH)
    print("GPIO-0 = ",gpio.read(12))

    r_stop = 0
    l_stop = 0
    u_stop = 0
    d_stop = 0

    max_left = 1425
    max_right = 0
    pan_pos = 0

    stop=0

    for i = 1, 8,1 do
        gpio.mode(mot[i], gpio.OUTPUT)  --  define output
    end

    function say_stop(s)
        if s == 1 then stop = 1 end
        if s == 0 then stop = 0 end
    end

    function ask_stop()
        return stop
    end

    function set_stop(l_s,r_s,u_s,d_s)
        l_stop = l_s r_stop = r_s u_stop = u_s d_stop = d_s
    end

    function get_stop(l_stop, r_stop, u_stop, d_stop)
        return l_stop, r_stop, u_stop, d_stop
    end

    function write_config()
        cf = file.open("config_data.cfg", "w+")
        if cf then
            cf.writeline(max_left)
            cf.writeline(max_right)
            cf.writeline(pan_pos)
            cf:close()
        end
    end
    -- write_config()  

    function load_config()
        cf = file.open("config_data.cfg", "r")
        if cf then
            max_left = tonumber(cf.readline())
            max_right = tonumber(cf.readline())
            pan_pos = tonumber(cf.readline())
            print("Werte geladen")
            print("max_left = ",max_left)
            print("max_right = ",max_right)
            print("pan_pos = ",pan_pos)
            cf:close()
        end
    end

    load_config()


    function sequence_l(a, b, c, d,mno)--gimbal dreht links

        if mno == 1 then       
            gpio.write(mot[1], a)
            gpio.write(mot[2], b)
            gpio.write(mot[3], c)
            gpio.write(mot[4], d) 
            tmr.delay(del)
        end
        if gpio.read(12) == 0 then l_stop = pan_pos end 

        if mno == 2 and stop == 0  then
            gpio.write(mot[5], a)
            gpio.write(mot[6], b)
            gpio.write(mot[7], c)
            gpio.write(mot[8], d)
            tmr.delay(del)              
        end
    end

    function sequence_r(a, b, c, d,mno)--gimbal dreht rechts

        if mno == 1 then
            gpio.write(mot[1], a)
            gpio.write(mot[2], b)
            gpio.write(mot[3], c)
            gpio.write(mot[4], d)
            tmr.delay(del)                       
        end
        if gpio.read(12) == 0 then r_stop = pan_pos end  

        if mno == 2 then
            gpio.write(mot[5], a)
            gpio.write(mot[6], b)
            gpio.write(mot[7], c)
            gpio.write(mot[8], d)
            tmr.delay(del)                    
        end
    end


    function turn(mno,direction,speed,steps)
        del = 100 * speed  -- bestimmt Geschwindigkeit

        if direction == 1 then  -- Gimbal turning right                 
            while pan_pos > max_right do --Rotation in one direction
                    if stop == 1 then break end
                    pan_pos = pan_pos -1
                    tmr.alarm(3, del, 0, function() sequence_r(gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno) print("timer 3 = ",stop)
                    end)
            tmr.unregister(3)                   
                    --sequence_r(gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.HIGH, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.HIGH,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH,mno)
                    sequence_r(gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH,mno)
            end
            sequence_r(gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)

        elseif direction == -1 then  -- Gimbal turning left
                while pan_pos <max_left do 
                print("turning left")
                if stop == 1 then break end
                pan_pos = pan_pos +1
                sequence_l(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.HIGH,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.HIGH, gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW,mno)
                sequence_l(gpio.HIGH, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH,mno)
            end
            sequence_l(gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.LOW, gpio.HIGH,mno)
        end

        print("-----------------------------------")
        print ("pan_pos=",pan_pos)
        print("Modul steps = ",steps)
        print("r_stop",r_stop)
        print("l_stop",l_stop)
        print("u_stop",u_stop)
        print("d_stop",d_stop)
        print("stop",stop)
        collectgarbage()
    end 
end

return stepper
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

I got a bit further myself. The main problem was (I think) that the called function that turn the motor was in a module. I have it all in one programm now. I am using a timer to produce some delay to slow the motor down. It works now for about 3 times motor start and stop. After that the motor keeps turning for about half a minute and only after that time the function reacts to the input from the webserver. It seems to be a timing problem.

Regards

Derek